# Showing certain functions depend only on one variable

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Suppose I have four functions $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_3, \lambda_4 : \mathbb{R}^4 \to \mathbb{R}$ such that

- for each $p \in \mathbb{R}^4$, there are at most three elements in $\{\lambda_i(p) \}_{1 \leq i \leq 4}$ (i.e. at most three $\lambda_i$ are distinct)
- $\lambda_1$ depends only on the first coordinate $x$ and for any $k \in \{1, 2, 3 \}$, the sum$$\sum_{1 \leq i \leq 4} (\lambda_i)^k$$ also depends only on $x$.

I want to prove that $\lambda_2, \lambda_3$ and $\lambda_4$ also depend only on $x$. Differentiating the above equation, it is clear that for each $j \in \{2, 3, 4\}$:

$$0 = \sum_{1 \leq i \leq 4} (\lambda_i)^{k-1} \cdot \partial_{j} (\lambda_i)$$

but I don't see a way from this to prove that $\partial_{j}(\lambda_i) = 0$ for each $j \in \{2, 3, 4 \}$. Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance!

---

Adding an additional hypothesis, Greg's comment solves the problem. Indeed, the problem is trivial if all $\lambda_i$ are equal, and if (without loss of generality) $\lambda_1 \neq \lambda_2 = \lambda_3 = \lambda_4$ or $\lambda_1 \neq \lambda_2 \neq \lambda_3 = \lambda_4$, the problem is solved with a simple analysis of the null-space of the matrix

$$\begin{pmatrix} \lambda_1^2 & \lambda_2^2 & \lambda_3^2 & \lambda_4^2 \\  \lambda_1 & \lambda_2 & \lambda_3 & \lambda_4 
 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 & 2 & 2\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Hmmm ... for fixed $j\in\{2,3,4\}$, you have three linear equations at the bottom of the post, together with the fourth equation $\partial_j(\lambda_1)=0$. Those four linear equations can be solved for the $\partial_j(\lambda_i)$: the coefficient matrix is essentially a Vandermonde matrix, and the only solution is $\partial_j(\lambda_i)=0$—unless $\lambda_a=\lambda_b$ for some $2\le a<b\le 4$....

Comment: @GregMartin thanks, but the problem is in my case I cannot assume all $\lambda_i$ are distinct.

Comment: @GregMartin adding an additional hypothesis to the problem (which is true for my purposes), your suggestion solves my question. Thanks!

Comment: If $\lambda_1$ depends only on $x$ you can reduce the considerations to three terms $\sum_{i=2}^4(\lambda_i)^k.$

Comment: Note that without differentiability, there are counterexamples: Take three $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ functions $f_1,$ $f_2$ and $f_3$ and make it somehow dependent on the second, third and fourth variable, if $(\lambda_2(x_1,\ldots,x_4)\lambda_3(x_1,\ldots,x_4),\lambda_4(x_1,\ldots,x_4))=(f_1(x_1),f_2(x_1),f_3(x_1))$ or $(\lambda_2(x_1,\ldots,x_4),\lambda_3(x_1,\ldots,x_4),\lambda_4(x_1,\ldots,x_4))=(f_2(x_1),f_3(x_1),f_1(x_1))$ or one of the other permutations. The sum of the $\lambda_i$, the sum of the squares and the sum of the cubes will still only depend on $x_1.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc thanks, I already knew that but it does help.

Comment: @ReinhardMeier that's interesting, thanks!

Comment: I think it helps as you can reduce the range of $k$ to $1\le k\le 3.$